# populate google spreadsheet based upon email text (not form)

Tags: gmail, google-sheets

I will like to populate a spreadsheet in a google spreadsheet based upon text in received emails. For instance, if a particular text appears in an email, value of a "counter" should increase. Is such a functionality possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably achieve this using Google Apps Scripts.

1 - To get data from Gmail into a spreadsheet: [the GmailApp class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/)

2 - To set up a spreadsheet with triggers: [Understanding Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events)

Then, using (2), set up a spreadsheet that either periodically, or every time it is opened, executes code using (1) that parses Gmail messages and writes to the spreadsheet. The following would be a good place to start:

3 - Tutorial: [Creating Gmail Inbox Statistics Report](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/gmail-stats)